# StaggeredGridLayoutManager item arrangement

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I am implementing below list using `RecyvlerView`. I have done it using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

[image].

**NOTE:** This screenshot is with `GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS`

Every thing works fine, but the issue is with order of item arrangement, it's arranging items like:

```
 | 0 | 1 |
 | 3 | 2 |
 | 4 | 5 |
 | 7 | 6 |
```

If you check above image you will notice 2nd item is drawing in Right side while 4th item is coming at left side but my requirement is to start every row from right side i.e 4th item will come in right side of grid. I have try both GapStrategy `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS` and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE`. If I use `GAP_HANDLING_NONE` then items are not visible yet functions of adapter are called but the output is
blank screen.
Is there any function to force StaggeredGridLayoutManager to start drawing from right side for new row?

I am calculating item height using below code:

```
public static void isSquired(View view, int position) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) view.getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        boolean isSquare = isSquare(position);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
        if (isSquare) {
            lp.width = width / 2;
            lp.height = width / 2;
        }else{
            lp.width = width / 2;
            lp.height = (width / 2)+70;
        }

        view.setLayoutParams(lp);
        view.requestLayout();
    }

    public static boolean isSquare(int position) {
        int mod = position % 4;
        return mod == 1 || mod == 3;
    }
```

RecyclerView initialisation:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
//manager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE);
manager.setGapStrategy(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: IIRC it lists everything in an `S` pattern, I dont think you can override that. Also things can get moved around as you scroll so your positioning in view isnt always going to be the same

Comment: @tyczj Can you suggest me any other implementation so that I can create this type of list and manage item ordering

Comment: @Jaiprakash Soni, Have you solved this problem?

Comment: No, I don't think it can be fixed.